# Requests parameters with non alphanumeric characters never match on lookup

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to retrieve a user based on their e-mail address using rest-frameworks `ModelViewSet`. Things work fine when there are only alphanumeric characters present in the request, however, it fails when characters such as `@`, `.` and `_` are included.

I've tried various requests, including:

```
GET /users/example%40example.com
GET /users/example@example.com
```

The response returns:

```
{
    "detail": "Not found."
}
```

Where the e-mail address in the request exactly matches that in the database.

Here is my current view:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'email'
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of the failing `GET` request? I would hazard to guess that the arguments are not being URL-encoded.

Comment: Updated the question to included some sample requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's me again, what I said yesterday was right, it's not the `@` symbol but the `.` symbol that is causing the 404 error. Change your code to:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'email'
    lookup_value_regex = '[^/]+'
```

The default lookup_value_regex  is `[^/.]+`, [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter) is the documentation.
Looking in the source code you can see it in `rest_framework/routers.py/SimpleRouter/get_lookup_regex`:

```
def get_lookup_regex(self, viewset, lookup_prefix=''):
    """
    Given a viewset, return the portion of URL regex that is used
    to match against a single instance.

    Note that lookup_prefix is not used directly inside REST rest_framework
    itself, but is required in order to nicely support nested router
    implementations, such as drf-nested-routers.

    https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers
    """
    base_regex = '(?P<{lookup_prefix}{lookup_url_kwarg}>{lookup_value})'
    # Use `pk` as default field, unset set.  Default regex should not
    # consume `.json` style suffixes and should break at '/' boundaries.
    lookup_field = getattr(viewset, 'lookup_field', 'pk')
    lookup_url_kwarg = getattr(viewset, 'lookup_url_kwarg', None) or lookup_field
    lookup_value = getattr(viewset, 'lookup_value_regex', '[^/.]+')
    return base_regex.format(
        lookup_prefix=lookup_prefix,
        lookup_url_kwarg=lookup_url_kwarg,
        lookup_value=lookup_value
    )
```